# android home button pressed

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

please check this code completely and suggest me some ideas
i had executed this in android studio 3.0.1 and showing me no error but doesnt shows any ouput

```
HomeWatcher mHomeWatcher = new HomeWatcher(this);
mHomeWatcher.setOnHomePressedListener(new OnHomePressedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onHomePressed() {
        // do something here...
    }
    @Override
    public void onHomeLongPressed() {
    }
});
mHomeWatcher.startWatch();
```

check this

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.util.Log;

public class HomeWatcher {

    static final String TAG = "hg";
    private Context mContext;
    private IntentFilter mFilter;
    private OnHomePressedListener mListener;
    private InnerRecevier mRecevier;

    public HomeWatcher(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
    }

    public void setOnHomePressedListener(OnHomePressedListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mRecevier = new InnerRecevier();
    }

    public void startWatch() {
        if (mRecevier != null) {
            mContext.registerReceiver(mRecevier, mFilter);
        }
    }

    public void stopWatch() {
        if (mRecevier != null) {
            mContext.unregisterReceiver(mRecevier);
        }
    }

    class InnerRecevier extends BroadcastReceiver {
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY = "reason";
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_GLOBAL_ACTIONS = "globalactions";
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS = "recentapps";
        final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY = "homekey";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)) {
                String reason = intent.getStringExtra(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY);
                if (reason != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "action:" + action + ",reason:" + reason);
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY)) {
                            mListener.onHomePressed();
                        } else if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_RECENT_APPS)) {
                            mListener.onHomeLongPressed();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

check this

```
public interface OnHomePressedListener {
    public void onHomePressed();

    public void onHomeLongPressed();
}
```

this code was not working for me i tried of toasting a msg when home button is pressed in onHomePressed() method but msg not display plz help me to get through it

Comment: Your extra and its values are undocumented. There are ~10,000 Android device models. Can you afford all of those to test on, to see if everybody is using this undocumented stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You aren´t supposed to see when users press the "Home" key, mostly for security reasons and consistent behaviour for the user.

(Except for special cases like Launchers)

Most methods of doing it have been disabled already, your method probably has been disabled aswell.